# Return memory address as out parameter in function

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I need to store the memory address of a string in an int pointer out parameter. I've created the code below to test the implementation.

```
void getMemAddress (int *a) {

    char str[80] = "Hello world";

    a = (int*)&str; // Assign memory address of str to a

    printf("%s", (char*)a);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int *memaddress;

    getMemAddress(memaddress);

    printf("%s", (char*)memaddress);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
printf("%s", (char*)a);
```

prints "Hello World" as it should but

```
printf("%s", (char*)memaddress);
```

prints null

How could I go about retrieving the actual memory address as using it to access the original string?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you trying to return the address of an object that no longer exists. That can't possibly work reliably.

Comment: Who's been on a downvoting spree and why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but likely it's because this question doesn't explain the problem that the person asking is trying to solve and as a result, it's not possible to give a good answer. (The question asks for help with a particular solution to an unspecified problem.)

Comment: @immibis well, all of the posted answers so far are wrong (an impressive feat)

Comment: @M.M The question asks how to return a pointer in the same way `void f(int *x) {*x=7;}` "returns" an `int`, no? There's also the local variable thing, but that's not explicitly part of the question.

Comment: It's still important to address

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parameters are passed by value in C. Similar issues have been answered countless times on stackoverflow.

You need this:

```
void getMemAddress (int **a) {    
    char str[80] = "Hello world";    
    *a = (int*)str; // Assign memory address of str to *a    
    printf("%s", (char*)*a);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *memaddress;
    getMemAddress(&memaddress);
    printf("%s", memaddress);
    return 0;
}
```

Casting a memory address to int won't work on a 64 bit system. On a 32 bit system it works, but it's not very clean.

Other problem. You are returning the address of a local variable that is on the stack. As soon as you leave the `getMemAddress` function the `str` buffer will be overwritten by following function calls (also a classic problem). Never return the address of a local variable.

Comment: `str` is on the stack. That will be a problem

Comment: Thanks, Did you purposefully change (int*)&str to (int*)str?

Comment: @user3255596 yes, `str` is already the address of the first byte of tht `str` buffer, the `&` is superfluous here.

Answer (score -1):

To modify something in a function, you need to pass a pointer to the thing you want to modify.

In this case you want to modify a pointer, so you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void getMemAddress (int **a) { // <-------------- added a *

    char str[80] = "Hello world";

    *a = (int*)str; // <-------------- added a *

    printf("%s", (char*)*a); // <-------------- added a *
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int *memaddress;

    getMemAddress(&memaddress); // <-------------- added a &

    printf("%s", (char*)memaddress);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, `&str` should be `&str[0]` or just `str`.

Also, `str` is a local variable, so it will cease to exist once `getMemAddress` returns (and then the `printf` call in `main` will *probably* print garbage). You could make `str` `static`, or you could return a pointer to a string literal instead (`char *str = "Hello world"; *a = (int*)str;`).

Comment: `%s` to print address?

Comment: @artm %s to print a string (a pointer to which is being stored in a variable of type `int*`, for some reason)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh right. Didn't notice it was a pointer to a local variable, not a string literal, *as well as* the problem I've fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You are assining the address of `&str` to your function-local copy of the pointer `a`. What you need is to modify getMemAddress so that it takes `int **a` as an argument, and assign it like this:

```
*a = (int *) str;
```

then in `main`:

```
int *memaddress;
getMemAddress(&memaddress);
```

And one more thing-- `str` only exists inside your function. Once you exit the function, you won't be able to access it. To fix this, make `str` a char pointer and use `malloc` to allocate some memory for it. Then use `strcpy` to insert your string.